# How do I linear search and compare two .txt files to see whats missing between them?

Tags: python, algorithm, search, linear-search

I'm trying to do a linear search on 2 .txt files. One is a story, the other is words from the story in a dictionary. What I'm trying to do, is search each file, then compare each word to one another, if a word is missing from the dictionary one, it should come back as misspelled and print it out. Searching is a little bit confusing for me so any help would be appreciated! The code in my while loop is the only example I have to work with, and I'm trying to modify it to fit my scenario. If you have other ways of doing it let me know, as Im struggling to grasp the Linear search concepts for comparing between what I have searched.

```
import re
# This function takes in a line of text and returns
# a list of words in the line.

def split_line(line):
    return re.findall('[A-Za-z]+(?:\'[A-Za-z]+)?', line)
# --- Read in a file from disk and put it in an array.


dictionary_list = []
alice_list = []

for line in open("dictionary.txt"):
    line = line.strip()
    dictionary_list.append(split_line(line))

for line in open("AliceInWonderLand200.txt"):
    line = line.strip()
    dictionary_list.append(split_line(line))



"""-----Linear Search-----"""
i = 0

while i < len(dictionary_list) and dictionary_list[i] != alice_list:
    i += 1

if i == len(dictionary_list):
    print("The Name is not on the list." + alice_list)
else:
    alice_list.append(i)
    print("The name is at position", i)
```

Comment: Your code adds everything to `dictionary_list`, also the story data.

Answer (score 0):

Use set difference.

```
"""
---------------------------
d.txt
---------------------------
alice
wonderland
alice-again
oh-dear-alice
---------------------------
alice.txt
---------------------------
aline
alice
oh-no-alice
---------------------------

"""

dictionary = list(open('d.txt','r'))
dictionary = set([i.strip() for i in dictionary])
#Once you have your list of words
#dictionary = set(get_dict_list())
input_file = list(open('alice.txt','r'))
input_file = set([i.strip() for i in input_file])
#input_file = set(get_story_list())
misspelled_words = input_file - dictionary
```